# How to create distro-specific conditional qmake project

Tags: qt, qmake, libs

Suppose I write code on 2 computers which runs different linux distros.

How to make qmake differ those two distros and assign specific LIBS for those two.

For instance;

```
unix: {

   ubuntu*: {
          LIBS += -lcxcore -lhighgui -lm
   }

   gentoo*: {
           LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lm
   }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can run "uname -a" and use a regular expression to check the return value in your .pro file:

```
UNAME = $$system(uname -a)

contains(UNAME, YourRegExpToMatchGentoo): GENTOO = 1
contains(UNAME, YourRegExpToMatchUbuntu): UBUNTU = 1

contains(GENTOO, 1): {
    LIBS += -lcxcore -lhighgui -lm
}

contains(UBUNTU, 1): {
    LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lm
}
```

Comment: Thanks @rogerzanoni, "contains" is what I was looking for. Changed your version into this: `GENTOO = $$system(cat /proc/version | grep -o Gentoo)` 
`UBUNTU = $$system(cat /proc/version | grep -o Ubuntu)`

`contains( GENTOO, Gentoo): {
    message(This is Gentoo)
    LIBS += -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_highgui -lm
}`

`contains( UBUNTU, Ubuntu): {
    message(This is Ubuntu)
    LIBS += -lcxcore -lhighgui -lm
}`